# ListBoxItem absolute position, Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, listboxitem

How can I get absolute (X,Y) position of ListBoxItem (top-left corner of it) according to whole ListBox and visible ScrollViewer area? Looks like there is no TranslatePoint() under WP7.

Answer (score 5):

Have found the way.

```
var selectedItem = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listBox.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
var transformToVisual = selectedItem.TransformToVisual(listBox);
var transform = transformToVisual.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```